# Node + Mongodb + ISODate + Timezone issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, utc, isodate

Hello I am working in node js + mongodb.

When I insert the data into collection the data is stored default ISODate eg. ISODate("2016-06-17T13:00:21.665Z")

I want to insert the date fields should be store in UTC.

Its already stored in UTC format or need to change anything in code ?

Please anyone suggest me.

My Code:

```
var query = {};
query.created_by = 'admin';
query.created_on = new Date();
var collection = mongoUtil.list;
collection.insert(query, function(err, item) {
    if (!err && item) {
        console.log("success");
    } else {
        console.log("error");
    }

});
```

Mongo inserted data:

```
{ "created_by" : "admin", "created_on" : ISODate("2016-06-17T13:00:21.665Z") }
```

I checked the refference - [Mongo UTC Refference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)
From Document:

1. Date() returns the current date as a string in the mongo shell.
2. new  Date() returns the current date as a Date object. The mongo shell
   wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper. The ISODate is in
   UTC.

Comment: what format are you getting in node.js?

Comment: pls tell me , how to check?

Comment: It's stored in the UTC format in your datastore. If you want to format the date in node.js you could use [moments](http://momentjs.com/docs/) plugin

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as mentioned in abdulbarik's answer, MongoDB does save the Date in UTC.

**Date Object:-**

You can use getTimezoneOffset() method to get the difference between  UTC and Local Time.

```
  var d = new Date()
  var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();

  console.log('date obj ==>' + d);
  console.log('time zone obj ==>' + n);
```

**Console log:-**

You can see the time zone obj has "-60". I am on **GMT+1**.

```
date obj ==>Mon Sep 12 2016 10:17:28 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
time zone obj ==>-60
```

**MongoDB has persisted the date in UTC:-**

I have used object "d" (i.e. new Date()) to persist the date in MongoDB. Though I am on GMT+1, the date is stored in UTC.

```
 "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-09-12T09:17:28.193Z"),
```

Comment: For me also now its storing the format like (2015-12-15T06:15:05.966Z)

Comment: so if i want to select query based on timezome or we need to handle in front-end ?

Answer (score 0):

If you directly insert or update Date, then you will store a timestamp. It will still be stored as the `UTC format` even it returns as UTC format when you query from `Node.js`.

But you may or may not want to trust that the time is correct. So for that you can create or use any method to make sure for UTC format.